# Как отправить фото пользователям бота? C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Как отправить фото с текстом, пользователям бота?

Answer (score 0):

**Первый способ** прописать команду, затем ссылку на фото, а после описание

```
using (NpgsqlConnection? connection = new(db.conn.ConnectionString))
{
   db.conn.Open();
   NpgsqlCommand command = db.conn.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, firstname FROM users_table";
   NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   List<string?[]> data = new();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       data.Add(new string[2]);
       data[^1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
       data[^1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
   }
   reader.Close();
   db.conn.Close();
   foreach (string?[] s in data)
   {
       try
       {
           string[] part = context.Update.Message.Text.Split(' '); 
           int lenghtPart = part[1].Length; // узнаем длину ссылки

           await context.Client.SendPhotoAsync(
           chatId: s[0]!.ToString(),
           photo: part[1], //указываем ссылку
           caption: context.Update.Message.Text[(14 + (lenghtPart+1))..], //обрезаем команду и ссылку c пробелом
           cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
           if (context.Update.Message.Type != MessageType.Photo)
           {
               await context.Client.SendTextMessageAsync(
                   1111111,
                   "Ссылка на фото не корректна. Попробуйте снова",
                   cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
           }
           else
           {
               db.conn.Open();
               NpgsqlCommand command2 = db.conn.CreateCommand();
               command2.CommandText = $"SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM users_table WHERE user_id = {s[0]}";
               NpgsqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
               List<string?[]> data2 = new();
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   data2.Add(new string[2]);
                   data2[^1][0] = reader2[0].ToString();
                   data2[^1][1] = reader2[1].ToString();
                   data2[^1][2] = reader2[2].ToString();
               }
               reader.Close();
               db.conn.Close();

               foreach (string?[] a in data)
               {
                   await context.Client.SendTextMessageAsync(
                       1111111,
                       $"Пользователь {a[0]} | {a[1]} | {a[2]} заблокировал бота",
                       cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

**Второй способ** если нужно выбрать с компьютера/телефона

```
var file = await context.Client.GetFileAsync(context.Update.Message.Photo.LastOrDefault().FileId);

await context.Client.SendPhotoAsync(
chatId: s[0]!.ToString(),
photo: $"{file.FileId}",
caption: context.Update.Message.Caption[14..],
cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```